# network flow problem--minimize weight of the edges in graph such that every special node has a flow 1

Tags: algorithm, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

Assume at first there is an unweighted graph.
We have a source in this graph and we want to send flow with value one to the special nodes specified before, so you must weigh the edges. If you put all the edges equal to infinity you can do this, but we want minimum weight for edges.

my solution: At first I put another source and connect the source to the special nodes with edges equal to 1 and other edges in the graph have infinite value. Then run the Ford Fulkerson algorithm in the graph. after doing this algorithm, every edge has a flow and I set the flow of the edges to the weight of that edges. But this doesn't meke the weight of the edges minimal.

How is this problem solved? Is this related to a famous problem?

Comment: it is a famous problem of min-cost max flow: find max flow while minimizing cost (every edge has a capacity and cost per flow unit). Basically you replace DFS part in fulkerson with bellmands ford or djikstra with potentials (https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/min_cost_flow.html)

Comment: @Photon I can't understand the relationship between this problem and my problem. my problem hasn't any capacity.

Comment: well you do have - you need flow of 1 to reach special nodes, hence capacity of edges from special nodes to sink should be equal to 1. All other edges capacity should be infinity - then as you said ford fulkerson will give the solution but not necessarily with minimum edge weights. Now if for all edges with infinite capacity you introduce a cost of 1 per flow unit - minimum cost max flow algorithms will minimize this cost so you will get the solution you need.